# How to connect localhost with another host name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to know how to connect localhost with another host name.

I tried using extra_host but it did not go well.

Is the writing style of docker-compose.yml wrong?

thanks.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  od-app:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 80:3000
    volumes:
      - ./app/src:/var/www/html
    links:
      - od-api:api.localhost*
    extra_hosts:
      - "test.example.com:127.0.0.1"
  od-api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./api/src:/var/www/html
      - /var/www/html/node_modules
```

Comment: it's a dns problem. You can do the mapping on `/etc/hosts` for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

`extra_hosts` in `docker-compose.yaml` just add the dns mapping `127.0.0.1 test.example.com` to container's `/etc/hosts`.

This means this dns mapping just effect inside the container, not be able to visit on host. If you want to visit container's service like using `test.example.com:80` from host, you should add this mapping in host's `/etc/hosts` instead.